# Is there a workaround to keep app settings which not defined in Bicep template?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep

main.bicep

```
resource appService 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2020-06-01' = {
  name: webSiteName
  location: location
  properties: {
    serverFarmId: appServicePlan.id
    siteConfig: {
      linuxFxVersion: linuxFxVersion

      appSettings: [
        {
          name: 'ContainerName'
          value: 'FancyContainer'
        }
        {
          name: 'FancyUrl'
          value: 'fancy.api.com'
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The infrastructure release process is run successfully, and the app settings are set correctly, after that I run the node application build and release where the Azure DevOps release pipeline adds some application-related config to app settings. (API keys, API URLs, for example) and everything works great.

But if I have to rerelease infrastructure, for example, I expand my environment with a storage account, the app settings which the application release set are lost.

Is there a workaround to keep app settings which not defined in Bicep template?

Comment: Not really. Any changes made outside of the BiCep file will be reset if they don't exist in the main. How I have done this in the past by using AzDo is to query the appSettings prior to the IaC deployment and then passing these back to the app after deployment.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

From this article: [Merge App Settings With Bicep](http://blog.dotnetstudio.nl/posts/2021/04/merge-appsettings-with-bicep/).

1. Don't include `appSettings` inside the `siteConfig` while deploying.
2. Create a module to create/update appsettings that will merge the existing settings with new settings.

*appsettings.bicep* file:

```bicep
param webAppName string
param appSettings object
param currentAppSettings object

resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' existing = {
  name: webAppName
}

resource siteconfig 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: webApp
  name: 'appsettings'
  properties: union(currentAppSettings, appSettings)
}
```

main.bicep:

```bicep
param webAppName string
...

// Create the webapp without appsettings
resource webApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' = {
  name: webAppName
  ...
  properties:{    
    ... 
    siteConfig: {
      // Dont include the appSettings
    }
  }
}

// Create-Update the webapp app settings.
module appSettings 'appsettings.bicep' = {
  name: '${webAppName}-appsettings'
  params: {
    webAppName: webApp.name
    // Get the current appsettings
    currentAppSettings: list(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/config', webApp.name, 'appsettings'), '2022-03-01').properties
    appSettings: {
      Foo: 'Bar'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If I have the webApp resource in its own module and call the webApp and appSettings modules from main.bicep then I get an error on the list function:  "This expression is being used in an argument of the function "list", which requires a value that can be calculated at the start of the deployment."

Comment: @OliverNilsen you're getting the webapp name / id as an output of the webapp module ?

Comment: Yes exactly. So the main.bicep deploys the module which defines the webApp resource.  Then right after that I deploy the appSettings module and provide webAppName: webApp.outputs.name as input param. It seems like the function list() can only be used inside the webApp resource module and not in the main.bicep.

Comment: you could always having the main invoking the webapp module and the webapp module invoking the appsettings module ? From my answer, my main become your webapp module.

Comment: that is a nice idea. I haven't thought of that one.

Comment: Currently, it's a limitation in what bicep is able to comprehend at "compile-time". When a resource is created in a module, it's outputs are considered "run-time" properties that we can't calculate upfront.

Comment: Does this work on first deployment? In other words, will it cause an error if there are no existing function app settings to list because the resource doesn't exist?

Comment: It should work. I did try while posting the answer and it was working

Comment: I'm trying to do the same thing for Azure Static Web App but it doesn't work.. Question can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77730853/combine-app-settings-from-portal-with-those-defined-in-bicep-template-for-static) if you might have the answer.