# Azure Bicep script : Ignore some manual configuration

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-api-management, azure-bicep

We are using Bicep script to deploy Infrastructure in Azure.

We have a pipeline that can deploy all configurations continuously to different environments.
We did not allow any change done outside of our script.

Question

While working with APIM service we want to attach a Certificate that we can not deploy through Bicep as the Certificate is not with us.

If we did a manual change in the certificate, the next time my bicep script runs, it will override the change.

How can we handle that few manual changes will remain as it is, and will not be replaced by my script?

Comment: In the APIM resource properties, if you 're not defining the certificates, is it working ? any other configuration ? which APIM properties / subresources are impacted ?

Comment: I have not tried that, will check but what is the ideal way of working? if we are not providing specific property will bicep revert it?

Comment: @Thomas you are right. If property removed from my service it is not replacing existing manual changes. Please add your comment in answer, will accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using ARM/Bicep templates, if you don't specify a property it won't override what has been defined elsewhere for this property (This is more or less true.)

If you remove the `certificates` property from your Bicep template it should work.

Comment: This is not true with app settings unfortunately.  The way bicep is working today is that your app settings will get deleted and recreated with what is defined in your template.
You should be able to do a union of the existing props within your bicep to get around this.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72940236/is-there-a-workaround-to-keep-app-settings-which-not-defined-in-bicep-template