# Azure function app WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE deployment problems

Tags: azure-devops, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service, azure-bicep

I have a bicep template that is run from a 'scaffolding' devops pipeline that creates an azure function app. This includes an app setting for WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE set to 1.

I have a separate devops pipeline that runs a dotnet build and deploys the function app's code zip into the newly provisioned function app. My problem is, this fails because it seems the function app is down - due to the fact that WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE is set to 1 and it can't find the code zip file yet.

I've described the problem in more detail [here](https://robbowman.github.io/2023/07/03/function-app-host-keys-missing.html)

Anyone else run into this chicken-egg problem?

Comment: so when you create the function app, you dont wanna set the WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE settings but once code is deployed this should be et and dont change ?

Comment: Hi @Thomas yes I think that should work. Just wanting to check my process / strategy for deployment is valid. I've not found anyone else complaining about this online which makes me think I'm doing something wrong

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72946083/4167200. You won't need to define WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE in your bicep file.