# Combine app settings from portal with those defined in bicep template for Static Web App

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-bicep, azure-static-web-app

So I have been following instructions from [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72940236/is-there-a-workaround-to-keep-app-settings-which-not-defined-in-bicep-template) and have successfully been able to merge app settings specified in the Azure Portal with the ones that is pushed through the bicep template, for an Azure Function App.

I am now trying to do the same for an Azure Static Web App, but I can't get it to work. Here is my code:

**resources.bicep**

```
(...)
param staticWebAppName string
param staticWebAppCdnLocation string
param staticWebAppSku string

param applicationInsightsName string
param applicationInsightsLocation string = resourceGroup().location

resource applicationInsights 'Microsoft.Insights/components@2020-02-02' = {
  name: applicationInsightsName
  location: applicationInsightsLocation
  kind: 'web'
  properties: {
    Application_Type: 'web'
    WorkspaceResourceId: logAnalyticsWorkspace.id
    RetentionInDays: 90
    IngestionMode: 'LogAnalytics'
    publicNetworkAccessForIngestion: 'Enabled'
    publicNetworkAccessForQuery: 'Enabled'
  }
  tags: tags
}

module staticWebAppMod 'staticWebApp.bicep' = {
  name: '${staticWebAppName}-deployment'
  scope: resourceGroup()
  params: {
    name: staticWebAppName
    cdnLocation: staticWebAppCdnLocation
    sku: staticWebAppSku
    applicationInsightsId: applicationInsights.id
    applicationInsightsInstrumentationKey: applicationInsights.properties.InstrumentationKey
    applicationInsightsConnectionString: applicationInsights.properties.ConnectionString
    tags: tags
  }
}

(...)
```

**staticWebApp.bicep**

```
param name string
param cdnLocation string
param sku string
param applicationInsightsId string
param applicationInsightsInstrumentationKey string
param applicationInsightsConnectionString string
param tags object

resource staticWebApp 'Microsoft.Web/staticSites@2023-01-01' = {
  name: name
  location: cdnLocation
  sku: {
    name: sku
    size: sku
  }
  properties: {}
  identity: {
    type: 'SystemAssigned'
  }
  tags: staticWebAppTags
}

var currentAppSettings = list(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/staticSites', staticWebApp.name, 'config', 'appsettings'), '2022-09-01').properties

module staticWebAppSettingsMod 'staticWebAppSettings.bicep' = {
  name: 'staticWebAppSettings-deployment}'
  params: {
    staticWebAppName: staticWebApp.name
    currentAppSettings: currentAppSettings
    newAppSettings: {
      APPINSIGHTS_INSTRUMENTATIONKEY: applicationInsightsInstrumentationKey
      APPLICATIONINSIGHTS_CONNECTION_STRING: applicationInsightsConnectionString
    }
  }
}
```

**staticWebAppSettings.bicep**

```
param staticWebAppName string
param currentAppSettings object
param newAppSettings object

resource staticWebAppSettings 'Microsoft.Web/staticSites/config@2022-09-01' = {
  name: '${staticWebAppName}/appsettings'
  properties: union(currentAppSettings, newAppSettings)
}
```

When I attempt to deploy the code above, I get the following error in my CD pipeline:

```
{"status":"Failed","error":{"code":"DeploymentFailed","target":"/subscriptions/***/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/main","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"ResourceDeploymentFailure","target":"/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/resource-deployment","message":"The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.","details":[{"code":"DeploymentFailed","target":"/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/resource-deployment","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"ResourceDeploymentFailure","target":"/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/***","message":"The resource write operation failed to complete successfully, because it reached terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.","details":[{"code":"DeploymentFailed","target":"/subscriptions/***/resourceGroups/***/providers/Microsoft.Resources/deployments/***","message":"At least one resource deployment operation failed. Please list deployment operations for details. Please see https://aka.ms/arm-deployment-operations for usage details.","details":[{"code":"BadRequest","message":""}]}]}]}]}]}}
```

Please note that the **main.bicep** and some other irrelevant stuff were omitted for readability.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `listAppSettings` function.

`appsettings.bicep` file:

```
param appName string
param appSettings object
param currentAppSettings object

resource app 'Microsoft.Web/staticSites@2023-01-01' existing = {
  name: appName
}

resource appsettings 'Microsoft.Web/staticSites/config@2023-01-01' = {
  parent: app
  name: 'appsettings'
  properties: union(currentAppSettings, appSettings)
}
```

and from the main template:

```
param location string = 'East Asia'
param appName string = 'thomasteststatic002'
param skuName string = 'Free'
param skuTier string = 'Free'

// Create the webapp
resource app 'Microsoft.Web/staticSites@2023-01-01' = {
  name: appName
  location: location
  sku: {
    name: skuName
    tier: skuTier
  }
  properties: {}
}

// Create-Update the webapp app settings.
module appSettings 'appsettings.bicep' = {
  name: '${appName}-appsettings'
  params: {
    appName: app.name
    // Get the current appsettings
    currentAppSettings: app.listAppSettings().properties
    appSettings: {
      Foo: 'Bar'
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, that did the trick. I looked all over in Microsofts documentation and couldn't find that info.. well well, thanks!

Comment: @Thomas  This is indeed a nice workaround. However, what I really do not like is that the 'What-if' diff gets so messed up when union() is used. Is there any possible way to make the diff also come out correctly showing the changes?

Comment: @RemEmber, tbh what-if is not so reliable, quite disappointing compared to terraform.