# Using bicep to merge existing appsettings with new values

Tags: azure, azure-bicep

I have a logic app (or any web app, as logic apps are now just sites).
It has configuration already. I now want to add 2 new config settings to this site.

So i have bicep similar to the following -

### settings.bicep --

```
param newSettings [object]

resource logicApp 'Microsoft.Web/sites@2022-03-01' existing = {
  name: logicAppName
}

var currentSettings = list(resourceId('Microsoft.Web/sites/config', logicApp.name, 'appsettings'), '2022-03-01').properties


//now union those settings with the newSettings object passed in here and set the Logic App config to this unioned object
resource siteconfig 'Microsoft.Web/sites/config@2022-03-01' = {
  parent: logicApp
  name: 'appsettings'
  properties: union(currentSettings, newSettings)
}
```

### main.bicep --

```
var connectorSettings = [
  {'auth' : 'something goes here'}
  {'runtimeUrl': 'something else goes here'}
]

module logicAppConfig 'settings.bicep' =  {
  name: 'extendedConfig'
  params: {
    logicAppName: logicAppName
    newSettings: connectorSettings    
  }
}
```

Is this the correct approach?
When i try this i get weird errors like this when i build up my new settings dictionary object

[image]

and then i get this when i try do the union

[image]

Anyone got any ideas here for me please?

Comment: This should help: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72946083/4167200

Comment: The type of `param newSettings [object]` will be an array containing one object element. Did you mean `param newSettings object`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using the right way to merge/update the existing resource property, But you may have a problem with the combination of properties. I have coded a sample for merging/updating logicapp resource.

origin logicapp resource `logicapp.bicep`. you should pre-deploy this resource

```
@description('The name of the logic app to create.')
param logicAppName string

@description('A test URI 1')
param testUri1 string = 'https://azure.status.microsoft/status/'

@description('Location for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

var workflowSchema = 'https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#'

resource stg 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01' = {
  name: logicAppName
  location: location
  tags: {
    displayName: logicAppName
  }
  properties: {
    definition: {
      '$schema': workflowSchema
      contentVersion: '1.0.0.0'
      triggers: {
        recurrence: {
          type: 'recurrence'
          recurrence: {
            frequency: 'Hour'
            interval: '1'
          }
        }
      }
      actions: {
        action1: {
          type: 'http'
          inputs: {
            method: 'Get'
            uri: testUri1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

below is used to update your above logicapp `logicapp_outputActions.bicep`

```
@description('The name of the logic app to create.')
param logicAppName string

@description('A test URI 2')
param testUri2 string = 'https://www.microsoft.com'

resource stgExisting 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01' existing = {
  name: logicAppName
}

var newAction = { action2: {
    type: 'http'
    inputs: {
      method: 'Get'
      uri: testUri2
    }
  } }

var newActionUnion = union(stgExisting.properties.definition.actions, newAction)

output newActionOutput object = newActionUnion
```

`main.bicep`

```
@description('The name of the logic app to create.')
param logicAppName string

@description('Location for all resources.')
param location string = resourceGroup().location

var workflowSchema = 'https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#'

module existingStg './logicapp_outputActions.bicep' = {
  name: 'testdeploy'
  params: {
    logicAppName: logicAppName
  }
}

resource stg 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows@2019-05-01' = {
  name: logicAppName
  location: location
  tags: {
    displayName: logicAppName
  }
  properties: {
    definition: {
      '$schema': workflowSchema
      contentVersion: '1.0.0.0'
      triggers: {
        recurrence: {
          type: 'recurrence'
          recurrence: {
            frequency: 'Hour'
            interval: '1'
          }
        }
      }
      actions: existingStg.outputs.newActionOutput
    }
  }
  dependsOn: [
    existingStg
  ]
}
```

> you should deploy twice, firstly deploy the `logicapp.bicep`, secondly deploy the `main.bicep` using the **same logicapp name** parameter to update it.